# Flutter Firestore different views for different customers

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a student-tutor app using flutter + firebase (auth and firestore).

I have a wrapper widget that checks if a user is logged in. If they're not, I direct them to an authentication screen (login/registration). If they are logged in, I then want to check if they are a student or a tutor.

In other words, in my wrapper, I need a way to retrieve user data from firestore and check their role and then direct them to the appropriate screen. I can't figure out how to do it. Please help. This is my wrapper class

```
`class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {

  static const String id = 'wrapper_screen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false); //FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()

    if (user == null) {
      return AuthenticationScreen();
    }
    else {
// I want to get user profile from firestore using user.uid and based on the role, show them different views
      return DeciderView();
    }
  }`.
```

You can think of an Uber clone, where I want riders and drivers to see different screens. How do I add this functionality? this is what I want my widget tree to look like: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDAD6.jpg)

Comment: "I want to get user profile from firestore using user.uid and based on the role" How do you store the role? In a Firestore document? In a Custom Claim?

Comment: I have a custom collection. Each user is a document with key = uid and two field: email and role. When a user registers, these details are taken from the form and a corresponding document is created in the collection.

Comment: If you have the user uid, just fetch the Firestore document: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/get.html

Comment: I see. My question may be too rudimentary but since this returns a Future, how do I use async/await in my wrapper class (stateless widget) to ensure that I get the results before directing the user to the relevant page?

Comment: @siaabd001 Use the "() async {}();" technique. This makes a function that runs itself instantly. Put your code inside the {}.

Comment: @JaffaKetchup where do I use it? if I understand correctly, it shouldn't be used in the build method since the build method gets called too often

Comment: @siaabd001 I'd personally use it in initState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `StreamBuilder` as it will rebuild your app whenever a change is made in the user's document.
The syntax might look somethig like this:
(If you already have user data saved on Firestore)

```
StreamBuilder(
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).snapshots(),
builder: (conext, snapshot){
if (!snapshot.hasData){
return Text('Loading');
}

final userData = snapshot.data.data();

if (userData['role'] == 'student'){
return StudentWidgets();
} 

return TutorWidgets();
})
```

Comment: thank you! I ended up using a FutureBuilder and it works.